# Find multiple, non consecutive, occurrences of a character in string

Tags: c#, regex, string

Can somebody please help me write RegEx expression which can check if a string contains more than one occurrence of a uppercase (or lowercase, doesn't matter) letter but not in a row.
I need to have at least two (or even better n) occurrences in a string. If n=2 valid situations would be PassWord or PAssword or PASSWord.

When I tried this `/(?=([A-Z]{2,3}))/g` it matched PassWOrd but not PassWord.

What is strange to me is that it also matched PaSSWOrd. I thought 3 in {2,3} actually means that no more that 3 Uppercase characters will be matched. Why is SSWO matched?

I tried similar variations but non of them worked for me (nothing strange as i'm not very familiar with RegEx).

Can this be done using RegEx?

Comment: Do you have to use a regex?

Comment: PAssword and PASSWord, accordingly to your description, should be one occurence, since all uppercases are in a row. Could you enlighten me, why it counts as two?

Comment: If `n=2`, should `PASSWord` be valid? I doubt it. You say there must be only 2 uppercase ASCII letters then, but there are 5 in this word.

Comment: I tested at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9hyfwC/2) it shows 3 matches for `PaSSWOrd`. `SSW`, `SWO` and `WO`

Comment: "Do you have to use a regex? "
Not necessarily, but this seems to be a good moment to try it, and learn

Comment: "PAssword and PASSWord, accordingly to your description, should be one occurence, since all uppercases are in a row. Could you enlighten me, why it counts as two?"

Sorry, not really sure what you are asking me. What i meant to say is, there needs to be specific occurrences, from n to m, of upper case letters in a string. For instance n=2, m=4, PassWord should be ok, PaSSwoRd also ok, PASSWORD is Not ok as it contains 8 uppercase letters.
Hope i managed to explain little bit better what my intention was

answer from  Wiktor Stribiżew should be what i was looking for.
thanks

Comment: If n=2, should PASSWord be valid? I doubt it. ......
Yes, you are correct. PASSWord should not be valid for n=2. 
Thanks for your answer, that is what i was looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(?=([A-Z]{2,3}))` regex matches 2 to 3 **consecutive** uppercase ASCII letters **anywhere inside a string**. You want to match a string that only contains 2 to 3 uppercase ASCII letters, not necessarily consecutively.

To match a string that only contains two uppercase ASCII letters (no more no less), use the following expression:

```
^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}[^A-Z]*$
```

Or, if you only allow ASCII letters in the whole string:

```
^(?:[a-z]*[A-Z]){2}[a-z]*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%5B%5EA-Z%5D*%5BA-Z%5D%29%7B2%7D%5B%5EA-Z%5D*%5Cr%3F%24&i=PassWord%0D%0APAssword%0D%0APASSWord&o=m).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}` - exactly 2 consequent occurrences of

  - `[^A-Z]*` -  zero or more chars other than ASCII uppercase letters
  - `[A-Z]` - one ASCII uppercase letter
- `[^A-Z]*` - zero or more chars other than ASCII uppercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

In C#, use

```
var strs = new List<string> { "PassWord", "PAssword", "PASSWord"};
var n = 2;
var pat = $@"^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){{{n}}}[^A-Z]*$";
foreach (var s in strs) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s, Regex.IsMatch(s, pat));
}
```

Result:

```
PassWord: True
PAssword: True
PASSWord: False
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/TtHGSE)

Note that in case you need to require 2 uppercase ASCII letters in a string where other chars can be any chars, you do not need a regex, use LINQ:

```
var strs = new List<string> { "PassWord", "PAssword", "PASSWord"};
var n = 2;
foreach (var s in strs) {
    var res = s.Count(c => (c >= 65 && c <= 90));
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s, res == 2);
}
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/yhMtp1). The `.Count(c => (c >= 65 && c <= 90))` part will count the uppercase ASCII letters anywhere in the string, and `res==2` will return a boolean result, whether the number is equal to 2 or not. It can be adjusted for a numeric range  check easily.

If you need Unicode compatibility, replace `.Count(c => (c >= 65 && c <= 90))` with `.Where(Char.IsUpper)`.